# MYSQL - Return distinct other value from two columns if either column contains x

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data in MySQL

```
C1 C2 //columns 1 & 2
XX AA
XX AB
AD XX
XX AC
XX AA
AA XX
AC XX
```

I am looking for a query string that returns the following result (does not have to be ordered)

```
AA
AB
AC
AD
```

A distinct (unique) list of 'other' column values present in either column when either of those columns in the table contains XX

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM (SELECT C2 
      FROM table1 WHERE C1='XX' 

      UNION 

      SELECT C1 
      FROM table1 WHERE C2='XX') t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(C1 <> 'XX', C1, C2)
FROM mytable
WHERE 'XX' IN (C1, C2);
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/XSUP73283)

Comment: Works exactly as needed thanks, is it possible to maintain this result set while adding a third column timestamp which shows the latest timestamp from that column for each distinct result? I tried SELECT DISTINCT IF(C1 <> 'XX', C1, C2), timestamp
FROM mytable
WHERE 'XX' IN (C1, C2) order by timestamp desc and it gave me duplicates again

Comment: @RayAndison `DISTINCT` is applied to *all* fields present in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will just run a nested second query on each of the distinct results from your first query that requests latest timestamp for each of these results. ie SELECT timestamp FROM mytable where C1 = 'firstqueryresult' || C2 = 'firstqueryresult' ORDER BY timestamp DESC, then apply the first result for each.That should get the result I need. Regards ;)